# Can't upload any file from html to flask

Tags: python, flask

I created this html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:https="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Upload Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="http://localhost:8887/upload/" method="post">
        <label class="btn btn-default btn-file">Browse
            <input type="file" class="hidden"/>
        </label>
        <br>
        <input class="btn btn-default" type="submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

So I'm trying to upload data from front end to back end. On back end side I'm using this code:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import request

app = Flask(__name__)


    @app.route('/upload/', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
    def upload():
        print(request.files)
        return 'hey'

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        app.run('0.0.0.0', 8887)
```

The result of the line `print(request.files)` is always

```
ImmutableMultiDict([])
```

I can't understand where is my mistake ?

Comment: uploading files is not just a regular request. Have you looked at the documentation for uploading files? http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/patterns/fileuploads/

Comment: @Craicerjack yeah, but what's the difference ? If I add `enctype=multipart/form-data` it won't work anyway.

Comment: Compare your code to the code in the docs and youll see theres quite a bit of difference. There is also a flask plugin for file uploads - http://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Uploads/. Other than that I dont see what you think is a mistake, a file upload isnt going to print out all the data thats in the file because its a file and not data as it might normally be. I presume its printing out `ImmutableMultiDict([])` because thats how its storing it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm no `flask` developer per se but as @Craicerjack already said, all you need to do a form upload is:

> 1. A  tag is marked with `enctype=multipart/form-data` and an `<input type=file>` is placed in that form.
> 2. The application accesses the file from the files dictionary on the request object.
> 3. Use the save() method of the file to save the file permanently somewhere on the filesystem.

The `multipart/form-data` makes a lot of difference because it **explicitly** says that:

1. There are going to be different mime-types in the request.
2. Your form data should not be encoded (if memory serves the other values are `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and `text/plain`).

Why the `multipar/form-data`? So the client (a.k.a browser) sends a multipart request that looks something like this

```
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/form-data;
boundary="----=_NextPart_000_0004_01D270B5.6F278C60"
my_post_variable = value
------=_NextPart_000_0004_01D270B5.6F278C60
Content-Type: octet-stream
3434352345345341223423
```

and the uploaded file goes after the `------=_NextPart_000_0004_01D270B5.6F278C60`.

Now, after all that explaining you should add the `enctype=multipart/form-data` to your form and remove the `GET` method from the route and that should get your upload going.